# Append column in csv file at specific index using java

Tags: java, string, eclipse, csv, append

I have a csv file which contains some data
e.g:

> Name,   Age
> John,     25
> Joe,    26
> I want to add a new column after the age. I tried a lot and here's my code

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\text1.csv",true));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String id[] = {"3","4"};

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        sb.append(id[i] + "\t");
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    br.write(sb.toString());
    br.close();

}
```

The values of `String[id]` is getting append but below 1st column. Also is there any way to add a header ?

Comment: lines are read and written horizontally after newline character, not vertically delimiter by delimiter. So read each line, transform each line by appending the new column and write each modified line back to the file.

Comment: So the concept i am using is wrong ?

Comment: Have you considered using [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) instead of inventing this wheel once again?